# The buttons all change the same color when they shouldn't

Tags: java

I have a total of 9 buttons. Each of them need to have an individual color that they will change to once they have been selected. As of right now, no matter which button is selected, they all follow the properties of the final color (in this case white) however I need them each to have an individual color.

```
import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton2;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton3;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton4;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton5;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton6;
    private JToggleButton Magenta;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton8;
    private JToggleButton jToggleButton9;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NewJFrame inst = new NewJFrame();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public NewJFrame() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            FlowLayout thisLayout = new FlowLayout();
            getContentPane().setLayout(thisLayout);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            {
                jToggleButton1 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton1);
                jToggleButton1.setText("Red");
                jToggleButton1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton1.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.RED);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton1);
            }
            {
                jToggleButton2 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton2);
                jToggleButton2.setText("Green");
                jToggleButton2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton2.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.GREEN);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton2);
            }               
            {
                jToggleButton3 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton3);
                jToggleButton3.setText("Blue");
                jToggleButton3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton3.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.BLUE);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton3);
            }
            {
                jToggleButton4 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton4);
                jToggleButton4.setText("Orange");
                jToggleButton4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton4.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.ORANGE);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton4);

            }
            {
                jToggleButton5 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton5);
                jToggleButton5.setText("Black");
                jToggleButton5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton5.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.BLACK);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton5);

            }
            {
                jToggleButton6 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton6);
                jToggleButton6.setText("Yellow");
                jToggleButton6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton6.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.YELLOW);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton6);

            }
            {
                Magenta = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(Magenta);
                Magenta.setText("Magenta");
                Magenta.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                Magenta.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.MAGENTA);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Magenta);

            }
            {
                jToggleButton8 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton8);
                jToggleButton8.setText("Pink");
                jToggleButton8.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton8.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.PINK);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton8);

            }
            {
                jToggleButton9 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton9);
                jToggleButton9.setText("White");
                jToggleButton9.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                jToggleButton9.setBackground(null);
                UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.WHITE);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jToggleButton9);

            }
            pack();
            this.setSize(350, 370);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Without taking a closer look, at every step you call `UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", ...);` with some color. The point is that the `key` for which you put in the color stays the same all the time. So the value stored under this `key` will be **overridden** at each call. So your items will all use the latest registered color.

Comment: I am still fairly new to Java, I have a basic understanding, so please be patient with me but, Is there anyway to get around this? Or do I just have to find a new way of implementing the color shift?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic. The problem is that your buttons all seem to get their color from the value put under the key `ToggleButton.select` in the `UIManager`. As said the value stored there is `WHITE` since you always override the value. You need some method such that the all buttons get their color from different sources, not all from exactly the same key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", ...);
```

This sets the default color for all selected buttons in your application.

To set the color of an individual button, you must use `setBackground`. Since you want to change the color when the button is selected, you have to react to an event and check the state of the button:

```
jToggleButton1.setUI(new BasicToggleButtonUI());
jToggleButton1.addItemListener(ev -> {
    if (ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        jToggleButton1.setBackground(Color.RED);
    else
        jToggleButton1.setBackground(null);
});
```

When you're adding the same logic to a lot of buttons, it might make sense to create a method and call it in your event listener:

```
private void updateColorIfSelected(JToggleButton btn, ItemEvent ev, Color color) {
    if (ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        btn.setBackground(color);
    else
        btn.setBackground(null);
}
```

And then:

```
jToggleButton1.setUI(new BasicToggleButtonUI());
jToggleButton1.addItemListener(ev -> updateColorIfSelected(jToggleButton1, ev, Color.RED));
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put each of the segments of code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DfiJX443 This is how I currently have it set up and it is not working

Comment: @Al-x Sorry, you have to set the button's UI to `BasicToggleButtonUI`, otherwise they ignore the background color. I've updated my answer. Your code looks fine otherwise!